# Can't find file of detailed error 404 IIS

Tags: html, iis, asp-classic

Ok,
I run a kind of game. Now I have an error which says basicly this:
iis 7.5 detailed error - 404.0

I don't know which file is missing, now I want to know where to find this 404 error. 
I can't find it in /inetpub/custerr/en-US/

Where can I find the DETAILED error message. the 404.html and 404-(1 to 12)
Doesn't house the detailed error. Where to find and edit the detailed error.

Thanks.

Comment: What? A `HTTP 404 Not Found` will fire when you access a page that doesn't exist, so it's the URL you are navigating to that produces the error, there is no more detail then that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are not managed by the files on the server but are managed by IIS.
If you want to find out where the error is on a page, you need to turn off the customer friendly error messages:

You need to alter the settings is IIS in two places to allow your to view the detailed error:

On the site with problems go to the '**ASP**' panel and make sure:

*Enable Client-side Debugging* = **True**.

*Send Errors to Browser* = **True**.

Then go to the '**Error Pages**' panel and make sure:

*When the server encounters an error, return* = **Detailed errors**

If you need to find out what page is causing the 404 error (document not found) then use a free online website link checker such as http://www.brokenlinkcheck.com/.